# Adding a background image in a bootstrap based blade template

Tags: laravel, twitter-bootstrap, laravel-blade

I have a laravel application.

I am using bootstrap in the frontend alongwith blade templates.

I want to add a background image to my landing page.

I am trying to style the page by putting a background image to the body. But its not working as in the image is not showing

Below is my code

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <title>Laravel</title>
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Arizonia' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

</head>
<style>
body {
 background-image: {{url('/images/gym_background.jpg')}};
}
</style>
<body>
@include('partials.header')
<div class="container">
    @yield('content')
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

In My chrome console i don't see any error of not loading the image.

The code for content section

```
    @extends('layouts.master')

@section('content')
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <h3>Welcome to your neighourbood Gym</h3>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
            <h1 class="post-title">Plans</h1>
            <p>Plans available in our gym!</p>
            <p><a href="{{ route('blog.plans', ['id' => 1]) }}">Click to view</a></p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <hr>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
            <h1 class="post-title">Gallery</h1>
            <p>Have a look around our gym</p>
            <p><a href="{{ route('blog.post', ['id' => 2]) }}">Click to view</a></p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <hr>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
            <h1 class="post-title">Contact us</h1>
            <p><a href="{{ route('contact.create') }}">Click for more details</a></p>
        </div>
    </div>
@endsection
```

Best Regards,

Saurav

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given the following folder structure:

```
`/public/images/gym_background.jpg`
```

Change this:

```
<style>
body {
 background-image: {{url('/images/gym_background.jpg')}};
}
</style>
```

To this:

```
<style>
body {

 // Add a . in front to look in the right folder + dropping the double {{ }}
 background-image: url('./images/gym_background.jpg');

}
</style>
```

Here is a good read on [relative vs absolute](https://phpdelusions.net/articles/paths) paths for the extra curious.

Answer (score 0):

<s>If you don't see the image and there's no 404 error in the network inspector, then probably your image is hidden under some other element that takes all the screen and has solid (white?) background. Try setting the same CSS on `div.container`, then it should work.</s>

UPD: Scratch that, the problem is curly braces. It will work if you remove those {{ and }}.

Comment: thanks for the reply..i added the style attribute to the div container "style = "background-image: {{url('/images/gym_background.jpg')}}" but still it did not work

Comment: I just noticed that you have {{ and }}, remove that

Comment: i removed and started getting 404...i thought the curly braces will be required if i want to resolve within the laravel resource resolution with blade templates...but the image is very well there...i see that the image is getting transferred as text/html in the network inspector

Comment: The image is where exactly? Is it in `/public/images/gym_background.jgp`? If you're getting 404, that means that the url is wrong, so you need to proper reference the image. Try opening it in a browser tab.

Comment: As @PavelLint mentioned, you're probably not referencing the folder structure correctly. You should try the troubleshooting method they mentioned. Also - try adding a `.` in front of /images

Comment: For example, an image stored in your `public` folder could be referenced by visiting `http://your-site.com/gym_background.jpg`.

Comment: @UkraineInTheMembrane thanks for your reply...adding "." worked...

Comment: Awesome @saurav ! I'll add it as an answer so that future answer-seekers can find it easily. Glad it helped you!